# WPF: Binding a Label to a class property

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the content of a label to bind to the string property of a class instance without much success.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFBindingTest.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">    
<Grid>        
    <Label Height="28" Margin="12,55,106,0" Name="label1" Background="Bisque"
           Content="{Binding Source=MyFoo, Path=W1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <Label Height="28" Margin="12,12,106,0" Name="label2" Background="Bisque"
           Content="{Binding Source=MyFoo, Path=W2}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,32,48"
            Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="89"
            Click="button1_Click">
        Set Properties
    </Button>

</Grid>   
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace WPFBindingTest
{
   public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Foo MyFoo;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            

            MyFoo = new Foo();           
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {      
            MyFoo.W1 = "Hello";
            MyFoo.W2 = "Dave";
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string W1 { get; set; }
        public string W2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i.e. when I click the button, I set the properties of MyFoo to "Hello" and "Dave", and want that reflected in the labels on the UI. I've set the Content as a binding but something isn't right. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may make your `MyFoo` a dependency property and set the `DataContext` to your `Window1` instance:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...>
```

See this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Making `MyFoo` a dependency property is not compulsory. it may work with just a property if you set the property value *before* assigning the `DataContext`. (But never with a field.) However if you want the labels to pick up the changing values of `W1` and `W2` (or you don't know/care if the values are set before or after assigning the `DataContect`), you need `Foo` to be either a `DependencyObject`, or implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. Made Foo implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then set the DataContext of Window1 to that of a BindingList<Foo>, which contains MyFoo. Label content is now:

{Binding Path=W1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}

And it works a treat!

Comment: @Vlad What would the difference be between using a `DependencyProperty` and implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or should this be a question of itself?

Comment: @ymw: this is a different question, in fact quite big. In short: both will work for just binding, but `INotifyPropertyChanged` is more lightweight, `DependencyProperty` however doesn't take memory if not used and can be used for animations, styling, templates, be inherited (from parent container to the contained element) and much more. See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3674530/276994).

Comment: @Vlad I know it's 6 years ago, but props must be given for a clear, concise and more importantly, UNDERSTANDABLE answer. I don't know why so many people struggle to depict the WPF UI element binding in a clear and simple way, but you've done it here!

Answer (score 15):

Or give your Window a name: like `NameOfWindow` and use a ElementName binding:

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=NameOfWindow, Path=MyFoo.W1}"
```

Complete sample XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFBindingTest.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Name="NameOfWindow">    
<Grid>        
    <Label Height="28" Margin="12,55,106,0" Name="label1" Background="Bisque" Content="{Binding ElementName=NameOfWindow, Path=MyFoo.W1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Height="28" Margin="12,12,106,0" Name="label2" Background="Bisque" Content="{Binding ElementName=NameOfWindow, Path=MyFoo.W2}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,32,48" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="89" Click="button1_Click">Set Properties</Button>
</Grid>
```