# Creating property for WPF user control datagrid

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a user control with a datagrid called IGrid. I want to add GridViewColumnCollection poperty for it.

```
public class DataGridNumericColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(System.Windows.FrameworkElement editingElement, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox edit = editingElement as TextBox;
        edit.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
        return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
    }
    void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(e.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

From Google i got a piece of  code `

```
private Collection<DataGridColumn> field = new Collection<DataGridColumn>();
[Category("Data")]
[Description("Column Creation")]                     
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public Collection<DataGridColumn> Columns
{
    get { return field; }
}
```

Here I can get GridViewColumnCollection  in visual tree ,
My question is how to add a new type (DataGridNumericColumn )in the collection  using the above code.

[image]

Comment: please any one respond

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know what the code does, it is probably best to research it before attempting to use it or come up with your own solution. As far as I can tell, you are attempting to add an additional property to a UserControl that inherits DataGrid.

You have two options:

1. Create a DependencyProperty (the best choice, in my opinion).
2. Create a normal property

Here's a couple links to help you get started:

[What is the difference between Property and Dependency Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674453/what-is-the-difference-between-property-and-dependency-property)

[When should I use dependency properties in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592630/when-should-i-use-dependency-properties-in-wpf)